# How to build a tree in Groovy from a database query?

Tags: groovy, recursion, tree

It looks like it returns the structure, but the values aren't there...

```
g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
root = g.v(1)

def tree
def results = []
tree = { vertices ->
  vertices.each() {
    children = it.out().toList()
    if (children) 
      results << tree(children)
  }
  results.toList()
}

println tree(root)
```

Here are the results...

```
$ ./gremlin.sh -e treeTest.groovy
[[], [[]]]
```

NOTE: I normally work in Python not Groovy so I am probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tree = { vertices ->

  def results = []

  vertices.each() {
    results << it
    children = it."$direction"().toList()
    if (children) {
      child_tree = tree(children)
      results << child_tree
    }
  }
  results
}
```